# SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found

Tags: java, mongodb, slf4j, mongodb-java

I am trying get the distict Milliseconds value from mongodb using java driver. But I get the above error.
Mongo version is 3.12.5 and also i have added all the maven dependency refarding sl4j i,e slf4j-api,slf4j-jdk14,slf4j-simple,slf4j-log4j12
My code:

```
 DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();

 searchQuery.put("date.iLocalMillis",BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", startSec).add("$lte", endSec).get()); //To get value between starting milliseconds to end milliseconds

      List CheckForDate = coll.distinct("date.iMilliSeconds",searchQuery); //adding search query criteria to get only distinct millisec values.
       for (Object o : CheckForDate) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
```

Still Warning shows :

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

And I dont get any results...

Comment: How do you run your program? Is there exactly one SLF4J provider in the class path? (slf4j-jdk14, slf4j-simple, slf4j-log4j12 are all providers; you must just add the one you are actually using)

Comment: Hey i just have maven dependencies of the above and i juts normally run the program in intelliJ

Comment: What is the MongoDB Java Driver version you are using? Version 3.12.x uses `java.util.logging`. From version 4.0 onward JUL is no longer used, it is SLF4J. See [Upgrading to 4.0 Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/upgrading/)

Comment: The java driver version i use is 3.12.5.  For version 4.0 is there maven dependency or do i have to download jar file?